# React how to filter arrays that do not contain specified value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have an array of recipes, I can filter for the ones that do include the ingredients I want but when I try to inverse the .some it then only proceeds to check the first item in the array.

my data is like

```
[
  {
   ...
   ingredients: [
     {
       "string of ingredients"
     }
   ] 
   ...
  }
]
```

and I made this method that can currently show ones that contain the string I want

```
const getData = (data, target) => {
    return data.filter((entry) => {
      return entry.ingredients.some((item) => {
        return item.toLowerCase().includes(target);
      });
    });
  };
```

but if I try to reverse it like the other ways ive tried it will not work unless its in the first index.

```
const getData = (data, target) => {
    return data.filter((entry) => {
      return entry.ingredients.some((item) => {
        return !item.toLowerCase().includes(target);
      });
    });
  };
```

or

```
const getData = (data, target) => {
    return data.filter((entry) => {
      return entry.ingredients.some((item) => {
        return item.toLowerCase().includes(target) === false;
      });
    });
  };
```

Im currently calling the filter by using

```
const newData = getData(oldData, "nut");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised its because when it checks the first string and sees it doenst contain the value I want it sets it to true which .some only needs one true value! so what I really needed to check was if every value doesnt contain it with .every instead!

```
const getData = (data, target) => {
    return data.filter((entry) => {
      return entry.ingredients.some((item) => {
        return !item.toLowerCase().includes(target);
      });
    });
  };
```